# change css picture with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

So i try to random my background every second but my background cant fix with my website so i need to using css for doing that ( cant do that with this code ) . So can we using css in javascrpit ?
this is my code

```
function changeBg() {
    var images = [],
    index = 0;
    images[0] = "0.jpg";
    images[1] = "1.jpg";
    images[2] = "2.jpg";
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    document.body.style.background ="#fff url('"+images[index]+"') no-repeat center center fixed";
}

setInterval(changeBg, 3000)
```

so i want all picture in this js to be using this css . how can i do that . Thank you guys so much :

```
 -webkit-background-size: cover;

  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

Comment: You don't need those vendor prefixes for `background-size`. It's [well supported](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_background-size).

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you asking how to apply a CSS rule to the body element?

Comment: What does `my background cant fix with my website ` mean?